# insert and join with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Can I insert data into MySQL by joining tables?

I have created my tables in this way and I can not change it. (**1**.Products. **2**.Photo and products id's. **3**.Photos.)

I am thinking something like this:

```
INSERT INTO products JOIN photoandproductids 
ON products.productid = photoandproductids.productid 
JOIN photos ON 
photos.photoid=photoandproductids.photoid 
(productname,productcategory,imagepath,imagepath,imagepath,) VALUES 
('test','test','photos/photo1','photos/photo2','photos/photo3')
```

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Please provide sample data and explain what you are trying to insert into.  If multiple tables in one statement, then the answer is "no".

Comment: I am trying to make an administrator form to insert new products with pictures. (with php)

Comment: You cannot insert into 3 tables at the same time.

Comment: Insert into each table separately - first the "parents" then the "children"

Comment: Can you share the DDLs of these tables?

Comment: Should I make 3 different forms for each of the tables?

Comment: @Mureinik what do you mean with ddl?

Comment: @Danny the statements used to create the table (e.g., `create table products (...`).

Comment: @Mureinik I have created them manually with phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Danny then share the table definitions (column names and types), please

Comment: @Mureinik This is for products. http://ovning.mehmetakb.se/products.png  This is for Images http://ovning.mehmetakb.se/photos.png And this is the relation between these two  http://ovning.mehmetakb.se/photoandproductids.png

Answer (score 0):

No. This cannot be done in a single `INSERT` statement. To insert rows into three tables requires three `INSERT` statements.

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

There are a couple of you could consider, like calling a stored procedure that performs the multiple `INSERT` statements you want to perform. But without a specification, we can't make any good recommendations.

We might assume that you are using AUTO_INCREMENT id columns. One possible pattern for accomplishing multiple inserts would be something like this:

```
 -- repeat this for each product to be inserted

    INSERT INTO products (product_name, product_category) VALUES ('test','test');
    -- if insert is successful, get the value assigned to AUTO_INCREMENT col
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
    -- save the value returned!


 -- repeat this for each photo to be inserted

    INSERT INTO photo (imagepath) VALUES ('photos/photo1');
    -- if insert is successful, get the value assigned to AUTO_INCREMENT col
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
    -- save the value returned!
    -- use the saved id values to insert to the linkage table

    -- repeat this for each productid that the photo is associated with
       INSERT INTO photoandproductids (productid, photoid) VALUES (?,?);
```

If you aren't adding a product, you would want to run a `SELECT` statement to get the productid. That is, if the id isn't available from the form, from a drop down list item selected by the user.

Comment: It will be an administrator page that our administrator can insert products with pictures and product information. (Size, Price etc). I have only these 3 tables and I must be done with admin page tomorrow. :(

Comment: And what language and/or framework are you using? Java Spring/Hibernate? Microsoft ASP? Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Spencer, I want to add values automatically for the last query. Is it possible? INSERT INTO photoandproductids (productid, photoid) VALUES (auto,auto); ?  The values will be the last inserted value + 1.

Comment: I am using PHP and Mysql and HTML

Comment: @Danny: to get that to happen, your code will need to retrieve the value assigned to an AUTO_INCREMENT column by an INSERT, immediately following the successful completion of the INSERT (in the same database connection), **`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`**. (Execute that query, and fetch the row from the resultset. The row contains the AUTO_INCREMENT value of the row that was previously inserted, save that in a variable, and then your application can supply that value in the `INSERT INTO photoandproductids` statement.